# Ruby 2D array to array of hashes with keys from different array

Tags: ruby, arrays

In Ruby, what's most efficient way of converting a 2D array of values to an array of hashes, where the keys are taken from a separate array?

For example, from:

```
keys = ['First name', 'Last name', 'Phone number']
values = [['John', 'Smith', '555-1234'], ['Peter', 'Jones', '555-5678']]
```

To:

```
[
  {'First name' => 'John',
   'Last name' => 'Smith',
   'Phone number' => '555-1234'},
  {'First name' => 'Peter',
   'Last name' => 'Jones',
   'Phone number' => '555-5678'}
]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do

```
array_of_hashs = values.map do |ary|
   keys.zip(ary).to_h
end

array_of_hashs
# => [{"First name"=>"John", "Last name"=>"Smith", "Phone number"=>"555-1234"}, 
# {"First name"=>"Peter", "Last name"=>"Jones", "Phone number"=>"555-5678"}]
```

Comment: Thanks! In Ruby 2.0 I had to change `keys.zip(ary).to_h` to `Hash[keys.zip(ary)]`.